# Cant load ggplot2 into R for Mac OS X

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-caret

I have downloaded the caret package to my local working directory:

```
install.packages("caret")
```

However when I try to load the library I get the following error:

```
library(caret)

>Loading required package: ggplot2  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in
> loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): 
> there is no package called ‘rlang’ Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not
> be loaded
```

I can see ggplot2 in my library:

```
lapply(.libPaths(),dir)
[[1]]....    "ggplot2"  ....
```

I am using R ver 3.6.2 for Mac OS X on OS Mojave 10.14.4
I haven't encountered this using R in windows, so any input appreciated .

Comment: What happens if you `install.packages("rlang")`?

Comment: yes that worked, I never noted this issue using R in windows, I wonder is it related to Mac X version only?

Comment: Nope, that package (and that error) is common to every platform. I can only imagine that at some point you installed something that included `rlang` in its dependency list, so it was installed for you.

Comment: Do you want to post as the answer so I can accept it, cheers

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an uncommon question. Without spending too much time researching, my guess is that this is addressed in one or more from https://stackoverflow.com/q/25721884/3358272. I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: No problem thanks again